# Where are the (class path?) strings found that I add to my dependencies hash?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

I have my `build.gradle` file and have been following tutorials to get it set up, but I am just wondering where these seemingly magic dependency strings come from?

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mustache')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin')
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.0.1-SNAPSHOT")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Somewhat secondarily, but perhaps this will be a good question in that it will be by way of example. I cannot seem to add the postgres driver to my dependencies. The tutorials I'm following all seem to produce an error of some kind. Teach me "how to fish" if you will and tell me where I can go to look up the magic string that will add postgres in to my project?

Comment: The problem with your postgresql dependency is that it is a SNAPSHOT version (test version) which is usually not deployed to the main repositories and require explicit configuring of the snapshot repository. For current versions, look at http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.postgresql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22postgresql%22 (take the one without jre6 or jre7 in the version string for Java 8 and higher support)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identifiers involved in dependencies declaration in Gradle build scripts are basically Gradle-specific dependency notation, which is then interpreted as a [module dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_types.html#sub:module_dependencies).

Module dependencies are, in other words, dependencies on modules that are published in some external repository and can be resolved. These dependencies thus come along with a [repository they are resolved from](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/repository_types.html). In build scripts, there is a `repositories { ... }` block for that. You will likely have popular centralized `mavenCentral()` or `jcenter()` in that block (and `google()` if you have an Android project), but you may also use a local Maven repository.

Since the dependencies are stored in the repositories, the module identifiers are also specific for the repositories. So you have to look up the repository for the module identifiers that you can use. The popular repositories are:

- [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) (`jcenter()`), here's an example of a [published module page](https://bintray.com/hotkeytlt/maven/better-parse), where on the bottom you can find the Gradle dependency notation that you can copy-paste into the buildscript.
- [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central) (`mavenCentral()`), and an example of a module page: [(link)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12)
- [Google Maven repository](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html), which is quite common for Android projects.

As to the Postgres driver dependency that you have troubles with, I suggest that you post a separate question and provide more details about the errors that you get, as that is a separate problem.

Comment: The mvnrepository.com site you're linking to is a third-party site, consider linking to https://search.maven.org/ instead

Comment: perfect! I did end up figuring that out, but this is a great writeup that expanded on what I was able to learn on my own. Thanks!